# What is tesseract confidence?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Seems like a trivial question, but I have not found a dedicated definition on what tesseract confidence value represents, not in the docs nor in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr/search?q=confidence)

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is too broad and needs more focus. Especially, the link points to a generic search for the keyword "confidence" in the group. Concepts like the confindence interval in stocastical system are very well explainable, but the question itself should be reworded to be easier to answer. In particular, the OP may want to provide context (e.g. link to a specific text) where the concept of `tesseract confidence` is used. I am no expert in OCRs but the wording does **not** suggest the concept of "confidence in the scope of Tesseract framework" whatever it is

Comment: I agree with you. The OCR field and everything related is unknown to me, so I presumed it is a term directly related to Tesseract. Closing it since I have a found an accurate answer in broader terms, as you suggested.